# Symmetric difference of sets, Ring

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

The symmetric difference between $2$ sets $A,B$ is $A \Delta B=(A \setminus B)\cup (B \setminus A)$. Let $Ω$ be a set. The characteristic function for $A \subset Ω$ is $\mathcal X_A:Ω\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathcal X_A(x)=0$ for $x \notin A$ and $\mathcal X_A(x)=1$ for $x \in A$. Let $\overline{\mathcal X}_A:Ω \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ be the function with $x$ modulo $2$.

1. Show that $\overline{\mathcal X}_A+\overline{\mathcal X}_B=\overline{\mathcal X}_{A \Delta B}$ for $A,B \subset Ω$.
2. Show that $(A \Delta B)\Delta C=A\Delta(B\Delta C)$ for $A,B,C \subset Ω$.

I already showed 2. but I don't know how to do 1..

Comment: Use the fact that $x\in A\triangle B$ if and only if $x$ is in exactly one of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Lena You're at great risk of being banned from aksing questions for quite some time. net votes on questions, including question of yours others delete, and questions of yours you delete after having been downvoted, all count equally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to show that $\overline{\chi}_A(x)+\overline{\chi}_B(x)=\overline{\chi}_{A\Delta B}(x)$, for every $x\in\Omega$ and $A,B\subset\Omega$.

So let $x\in\Omega$.
There are three cases to consider.
$x\in A$ and $x\notin B$.
$x\in A$ and $x\in B$.
$x\notin A$ and $x\notin B$.

The first case would play out like this:

We have that $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$. Therefore $x\in A\Delta B$. (Why?)

Hence

$\underbrace{\overline{\chi}_A(x)}_{=1}+\underbrace{\overline{\chi}_B(x)}_{=0}=\underbrace{\overline{\chi}_{A\Delta B}(x)}_{=1}$

So $1+0=1$, which is correct.

I leave the other cases to you.

Answer (score 0):

$\overline{\mathcal X}_A(x)+\overline{\mathcal X}_B(x)=0\Leftrightarrow{\mathcal X}_A(x)+{\mathcal X}_B(x)=0,2\Leftrightarrow (x\notin A\land x\notin B)\lor(x\in A\land x\in B)\Leftrightarrow (x\in\Omega\setminus A\land x\in\Omega\setminus B)\lor(x\in A\cap B)\Leftrightarrow x\in (\Omega\setminus A)\cap(\Omega\setminus B)=\big((\Omega\setminus A)^\mathsf c\cup(\Omega\setminus B)^\mathsf c\big)^\mathsf c=\big(A\cup B)^\mathsf c\lor (x\in A\cap B)\Leftrightarrow x\in(A\Delta B)^\mathsf c\Leftrightarrow{\mathcal X}_{A \Delta B}=0\Leftrightarrow \overline{\mathcal X}_{A \Delta B}=0$

Can you do the other case?

Comment: Why the downvote?